# .iso vs .cdr format?

Tags: disk-volume, dvd-player

My Macbook Pro optical drive is out of commission.

If I use my sister's Windows 10 or Windows XP to make an ISO file from a DVD and bring over by sneakernet, will I be able to play it as a DVD?

Or can it be converted to .cdr?

Comment: If your optical drive is out of commission, what good is creating a DVD on a Windows machine and "bringing it over by sneakernet"?  Won't the drive **still** be out of commission?  Voting to close as unclear...

Comment: I think it's your reading that's unclear.  Steve read more carefully and answered the actual question.

Comment: @WGroleau no your wording is unclear. The first sentence makes us look at the optical drive. Better just to ask can a you save a DVD in Windows as a file and copy over to macOS

Comment: That _is_ what I asked, _and_ quoted in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS will recognize both an .iso, .cdr and .dmg (for that matter) as a standard disk image.

Copy it to the Mac and double click on it and it should mount on the desktop and recognize it as standard DVD...

...**ASSUMING** that the DVD does not have some copy protection built-in that will prevent a simple disk image copy. Unfortunately that is likely and you may want to look into Windows compatible software that will enable copying commercial DVDs.

Comment: Well, I doubt Windows can create a DMG.  But thanks for the reassuring answer.  Seems the local "Megabyte" has an interesting definition of "refurbish"—hardware test says battery problems, SD reader is dead, bluetooth is flaky, and USB ports can't charge an iPad mini.

Comment: re the refurbishment I would return that machine and get them to replace or provide a working machine

Comment: I told them that I expect a full refund when I return from Spain, and if I have to buy a replacement in Spain, I expect them to pay for it.  I wonder if Apple will revoke their status after hearing this.  Even though I am extremely displeased, I'd hate for everyone in this area to have to go to Best Buy.